# PHP JSON Encode issue

Tags: php, json

I am trying to encode a response as JSON so I can extract some data from it.

The data is:

```
{ "StatusCode": 0, "StatusInfo": "Command Processed OK",
"BranchNumber": "1000", "CustomerId": "98295950", "CustomerName":
"Mrs. Anonymously-Loggedin", "SessionKey":
"jBRBVlf35xFhIoq5nLQ5yaVpR2TjIDIEjBbyh5yYRW5Ky8bDG4",
"InAmendOrderMode": "N", "BasketID": "", "ChosenDeliverySlotInfo":
"Not applicable with anonymous login", "CustomerForename": "" }
```

I run:

```
$result = json_encode($result);
echo $result;
```

and get 'true'.

What am I doing wrong?

NB: This isn't someone unable to use JSON_Decode; this is a genuine problem, I've tried treating it as objects, encoding/decoding as JSON/UTF-8 but all I get is errors or NULL values.

Comment: data already encoded. You can decode this using php `json_decode()` function

Comment: Doesn't work, returns '1' now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly for me.

`$result = json_decode('jsonGoesHere');
echo $result->StatusCode;`

Make sure your data is going in as a string otherwise it'll break.

Answer (score 1):

The data is already JSON-encoded. To work with it, you need to decode it using `json_decode` as follows:

```
$result = '{ "StatusCode": 0, "StatusInfo": "Command Processed OK", "BranchNumber": "1000", "CustomerId": "98295950", "CustomerName": "Mrs. Anonymously-Loggedin", "SessionKey": "jBRBVlf35xFhIoq5nLQ5yaVpR2TjIDIEjBbyh5yYRW5Ky8bDG4", "InAmendOrderMode": "N", "BasketID": "", "ChosenDeliverySlotInfo": "Not applicable with anonymous login", "CustomerForename": "" }';
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, I think `$result` is a javascript object, rather than a literal JSON string, in which case, you may need to enclose it in quotes, as shown below:

```
$data   = json_decode( "'$result'", true);
```

You can then proceed to access the data members as:

```
$status_code = $data['StatusCode'];
$status_info = $data['StatusInfo'];
...
```

I hope you can take it from there.

Comment: That isn't working sorry, I've tried that.
a var_dump of those variables returns NULL

Comment: There must be something else we are not seeing. Can you paste more of your code in your question?

Comment: The only other part is the cURL request; to the Tesco API.

Comment: I think `$result` is a javascript object, in which case, you may need to surround it with quotes. Updating my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Sorry, Var_Dump is still returning NULL of $status_code etc.

Comment: "still returning NULL of $status_code etc", can you show the output of `var_dump`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


$url = 'https://secure.techfortesco.com/tescolabsapi/restservice.aspx?';

$result = file_get_contents(http://...);

$result = json_decode($result); 
echo $result->StatusCode;

?>
```

Solved by using file_get_contents instead of cURL and treating as an object. 
**EDIT**
Looks like cURL returns a proper JSON object which can't be decoded nor treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

$result is an object :

```
$result = json_decode('{ "StatusCode": 0, "StatusInfo": "Command       Processed OK", "BranchNumber": "1000", "CustomerId": "98295950", "CustomerName": "Mrs. Anonymously-Loggedin", "SessionKey": "jBRBVlf35xFhIoq5nLQ5yaVpR2TjIDIEjBbyh5yYRW5Ky8bDG4", "InAmendOrderMode": "N", "BasketID": "", "ChosenDeliverySlotInfo": "Not applicable with anonymous login", "CustomerForename": "" }');

echo $result->StatusCode;
echo $result->StatusInfo;
```

Comment: Returns: 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/index.php on line 18'

Comment: This works perfectly for me. as the answer you have validated